# Usar JavaScript para mudar propriedade no CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar, eu tenho um menu lateral retratil e um botão em uma barra no cabeçalho. Eu setei meu menu para `margin-left: -250px;` e queria que quando eu apertasse o botão ele setasse para `margin-left: 0;`, fazendo assim o menu aparecer novamente.

CSS do menu:

```css
#menu-lateral {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
}
```

HTML do botão:

```html
<div class="btn-header">
      <a href="" id="btn-menu">
      <img src="img/menu.png">
      <img src="img/icone.png">
      <p>Home</p></a>
</div>
```

JavaScript que eu fiz:

```js
    var clique = document.getElementById("btn-menu"); 
    var menuLateral = document.getElementById("menu-lateral");

    clique.onclick = function(){
        document.menuLateral.style.marginLeft = "0";
    };
```

Meu objetivo é:

Ao clicar no botão mudar em `#menu-lateral` o `margin-left: -250px;` para `margin-left: 0;` e que quando o menu estiver aberto, se clicar novamente ele fecha(setando o `margin-left: -250px;` novamente).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tens de mudar duas coisas:

Primeiro deves usar `e.preventDefault();` para impedir que o link recarregue a página, ou juntar `#` no `href`.

Segundo tu declaras uma *variável* que aponta para o menu, `var menuLateral = document.getElementById("menu-lateral");`. Mais à frente no código em vez de usar a variável usas `document.menuLateral.style...` quando devias usar somente `menuLateral.style...`

Corrigido fica assim:

```js
clique.onclick = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    menuLateral.style.marginLeft = "0";
};
```

**Exemplo** (com CSS transition também): **http://jsfiddle.net/zjevj1vv/**

**Podes fazer isso também via classe de CSS**, nesse caso aplicas o estilo novo via CSS que é melhor. Um exemplo de como fazer *toggle* seria:

CSS

```css
.toggleMenu {
    margin-left: 0px !important;
}
```

JavaScript

```js
clique.onclick = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    menuLateral.classList.toggle('toggleMenu');
};
```

O `toggle` adiciona uma classe e/ou remove se ela já existir. É como o botão do comando da televisão, carrega para ligar/desligar.
O `!important` é para dizer que quando essa classe for adicionada então essa regra sobrepõe-se à outra de `margin-left: -250px;`.
O `transition`, diz que a mudança deve ser por animação e com duração de `0.7` segundos

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zjevj1vv/1/

Comment: eu vi que tinha o document la e tirei, mas ele só piscava na tela u.u

Comment: Mas me diz uma coisa, como eu coloco um toggle ou algo assim pra quando eu clicar no botão novamente ele retrair?

Comment: @AndreyHartung nesse caso podes fazer assim, usando uma classe de CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/zjevj1vv/1/

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu queria! MUITO Obrigado! Mas me diga, tu poderia me explicar como funciona? Sou novo nesse mundo de programador web :/ ou um lugar para eu ler sobre isso seria ótimo, porque eu não consegui encontrar nada bom.

Comment: @AndreyHartung que parte não percebeste para eu explicar melhor? ou melhor, que parte percebeste?

Comment: o toggle desfaz o que o clique anterior fez? Porque tu setou o !important? Esse transition serve só pra controlar a velocidade que o menu aparece/desaparece?

Comment: @AndreyHartung o `toggle` adiciona uma classe e remove se ela já existir. É como o botão do comando da televisão, carrega para ligar/desligar. O `!important` é para dizer que quando essa classe for adicionada então essa regra sobrepõe-se à outra de `margin-left -250px`. Por fim, o transition, diz que a mudança deve ser por animação e com duração de `0.7` segundos

Comment: então isso significa que ele adiciona a classe toggleMenu a mesma tag que a classe menu-lateral estiver? De novo, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @AndreyHartung ele adiciona ou retira ao elemento que `menuLateral` apontar.