# Mudar cor de links visitado

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde!

Gostaria de saber como posso mudar cor de links visitado em uma página usando javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o marcador no próprio css:

`a:visited { 
    color: pink;
}`

Fonte: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp

Via javascript há o método de alterar o css:

[Usar JavaScript para mudar propriedade no CSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58863/usar-javascript-para-mudar-propriedade-no-css)